# Join array elements with space in Bash not working

Tags: arrays, bash, concatenation, cat

I'm trying to concatenate the contents of a list of files from a remote server into one. My code was trying to first get a list of their paths into an array, which I successfully did:

```
day_of_week=`date +%w`
if [[ $day_of_week == 1 ]]; then
  look_back=3
else
  look_back=1
fi
DATE=$(date -d "$look_back day ago" '+%Y%m%d')
SLAP_PATH="/ns/local/data/internal/SUBM/data/SLAP_376_SUBM1/data/${DATE}/processed/"
FILES=$(ssh -tq myuser@myserver "find ${SLAP_PATH} -type f -name 'subm_*lfj_in.csv'")
```

FILES variable:

```
/ns/local/data/internal/SUBM/data/SLAP_376_SUBM1/data/20200129/processed/subm_144_lfj_in.csv
/ns/local/data/internal/SUBM/data/SLAP_376_SUBM1/data/20200129/processed/subm_140_lfj_in.csv
/ns/local/data/internal/SUBM/data/SLAP_376_SUBM1/data/20200129/processed/subm_145_lfj_in.csv
(...)
```

So now I'm trying to concatenate each value into a string variable called "CMD", so then I can try to use something like:

```
cat file1 file2 file3... > final_file
```

The problem is that I can't create the sequence of file names. Here is my code:

```
CMD=""
for ((i = 0; i < ${#FILES[@]}; i++)); do
   #remove \n
   tmp=`echo ${FILES[$i]} | tr -d '\n'`
   #concatenate into $CMD:
   CMD="$CMD $tmp"
done
echo "This is CMD: $CMD"
```

And every time that I run my script, this is what I get:

```
$$ ./exportReconData.sh
/ns/local/data/internal/SUBM/data/SLAP_376_SUBM1/data/20200129/processed/subm_147_lfj_in.csv44_lfj_in.csv
```

Any suggestions? Maybe there's a much easier way of doing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FILES` is not an array. To create an array, you need to put `()` around the value in the assignment:

```
IFS=$'\n\r' # so spaces won't delimit array elements
FILES=($(ssh -tq myuser@myserver "find ${SLAP_PATH} -type f -name 'subm_*lfj_in.csv'"))
```

Comment: Another problem that I've just realized: my lines were coming with a '\r' in the end. Had to use "i=`echo "$i" | sed 's/\\r//g'`" to remove those.

Comment: You can put `\r` in `IFS`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate the files, then do so.  You don't need the paths to them in a separate variable:

```
ssh myuser@myserver "find ${SLAP_PATH} -type f -name 'subm_*lfj_in.csv' -exec cat {} +" >final_file
```

I've also removed `-t` from `ssh` since there's really no reason to allocate a pseudo-tty.  I've also removed `-q`, because diagnostic messages are usually outputted for a reason.

If you want the `final_file` on the remote host, then move the redirection into the command executed remotely.